Location of installed with homebrew postgresql data directory on MacOS Sonoma
Everywhere on the internet, it says /usr/local/var/postgres. But it is not the case on my Mac.

Welcome to Ask Different. There’s a general tool for this: brew --prefix

I found that it is actually located here on my Mac: /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@14 
